# Relay other network shared directores?

Tags: windows, smb

For example, there is `Server1`, `Server2`, and `Server3`. They are just plain Windows computers, not joined to a domain. Suppose that only `Server1` is publically known. Suppose that each server has a shared directory `SharedDir`.

Is it possible to attach the shared directories of other servers to `Server1`, so that users can access all three directories from `Server1`, as if all three directories actually exist on `Server1` (transparent to the user)?

`\\Server1\SharedDir`

`\\Server1\SharedDir2` --> actually `\\Server2\SharedDir`

`\\Server1\SharedDir3` --> actually `\\Server3\SharedDir`

Users provide only one credential to log in to `\\Server1`, and `Server1` its own credential to access `\\Server2\SharedDir` and `\\Server3\SharedDir`, so to `Server2` and `Server3`, it would look as if a user on `Server1` is accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

Map other two shares as drive letters on server1 and share those new drives

Comment: This may work, but it would improve the answer if you expanded a bit on the process of doing so.